# Downloading embedded video from URL with wget

Tags: video, terminal, homebrew, wget

I was on the news today and would like to download the video from their web page. I have been strugling with terminal for an hour now. What is the best way to download a video like this?

https://www.kens5.com/video/money/business/made-in-sa/made-in-sa-ragnar-handcrafted-furniture-and-sawmill/273-622570f2-900a-44d5-af57-bea8a40bacea?jwsource=cl

I ran an older version of wget which was having SSL problems. I updated my homebrew instal and reinstaled wget. I have the new wget instaled but not linked. I have tried `brew link wget` but get an error because of this folder not being writable. I have tried to `sudo rm /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES` and reinstal. I have also tried `sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES`

This is the error I get:
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.20.3_1...
Error: Could not symlink share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
/usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.

Comment: try running `brew doctor`

Comment: when I run brew doctor I have two kegs unlinked, one of which is wget. I get the same not writable error when I try to link those.

Comment: I recommend that this question be asked on superuser.coM since it in not a programming, but support question

Comment: thank you szatmary. I will post it there.

Comment: Take back the ownership of `/usr/local` and try again: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`